# How to fix repository error?

Tags: apt, sudo, update-manager, repository

I am using Ubuntu 23.04. When I do the `sudo apt update`, it gives me following repository error. How can I fix it?

```
    Hit:1 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
    Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease               
    Hit:3 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease              
    Hit:4 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease            
    Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu lunar InRelease                 
    Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease    
    Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release
      404  Not Found [IP: (my ip)]
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Contact the PPA owner to fix his PPA. There is nothing here that can be solved within Ubuntu.

Comment: PPA's are *Personal Package Archives* where all security checks are on you to perform; I'd have expected those checks, if performed by you, would have seen that no support for Ubuntu 23.04 or *lunar* is given by that source - and thus not have added it.  Did you examine https://launchpad.net/~peterlevi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  (*which was taken from your provided details*)